# Installing and using npTDMS with Spyder - anaconda3

Tags: python, package, spyder

I have successfully installed npTDMS as seen here:
https://pypi.org/project/npTDMS/

If I try to install with command line using either pip or conda I get a message confirming it is already installed, and I see the package at `D:\Users\username\anaconda3\pkgs`.

On Spyder I have tried using the PYTHON path manager (in the tools menu) to add both:

```
D:\Users\username\anaconda3\pkgs\nptdms-1.2.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
D:\Users\username\anaconda3\pkgs\nptdms-1.2.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0\site-packages\nptdms
```

As far as I understand this should be enough to use the npTDMS package, however when I try to import I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nptdms'`.

I'm fairly new to python overall so maybe there is a simple thing I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

This issue comes when there are multiple versions of python or any package you are running at current time. The same issue was with me too when the IDLE was not able to detect the position of where the package is installed.

My suggestion is that uninstall all the versions of python and the module you are using and install them again. Otherwise shift to any other IDLE, in my recommendation - Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I uninstalled Spyder and installed it through the Anaconda Navigator.

I'm guessing you're right and it was using a different version of python than I thought. I had installed it with very little knowledge of Python (Not that I have a lot more now)

On the IDLE topic - with little experience it's hard to tell the benefits of one over the other. So far I'm happy with what Spyder has to offer but am interested in the benefits of others.